# Installing Caffe in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, python, cmake, caffe

So I am currently installing Caffe and I'm already in this part:

> No, this does not help the Ubuntu 16.04 for now. You could try to pass an argument (CXX_FLAGS) to the compiler -D_FORCE_INLINES by editing the CMAKE files (for example: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_FORCE_INLINES")) or makefiles. The procedure is not specified. This should work, or you must wait for an updated Cuda Toolkit sources to compile with the associated software in Ubuntu 16.04 such as Caffe, Torch and Theano.

I'm following this guide: https://github.com/intel/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide

I don't exactly know what this means. Can someone please explain this to me in detailed steps? Thank you!

Comment: If you don't get an adequate answer here, I'd recommend asking on the [Caffe Users Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caffe-users)

Comment: Also, the installation instructions here seem a bit simpler: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html

Comment: FYI [Installation instructions for Caffe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31396229/395857)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct answer to your question about BUILDING caffe, i found the best way to get up and running is to use conda. First start by making an environment

```
conda create -n caffe
```

then

```
conda install caffe
```

OR

```
conda install caffe-gpu
```

Not only does conda solve all the dependencies but it also installs the correct version of cudatoolkit and cudnn. And if you want python 2 you can

```
conda create -n python2Caffe-GPU python=2.7

conda install caffe-gpu=1.0=py27heda4471_3
```

The variable, py27heda4471_3, is the build version and you have many to choose from

```
conda search caffe-gpu
```

gives a list